# Practicing guitar in a small space

Tags: electric-guitar

How do you setup your gear if you have a small space? My gear should allow me to:

Use headphones
Sound reasonable including effects
Allow plugin of a music source for playback

If u can recommend a device of the sort that would be great thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A great Program that you can get on your phone, iPad, computer, tablet, etc. is **Bias FX**. To get this running, all you will need is a device to plug your guitar into (audio interface); a great quality, cheap audio interface for tablets is the iRig, I believe it also works with PC. Bias FX will provide you with all your needed pedals, stompboxes and tones without the need for an actual amp, you can then run this through the devices speakers or more recommended, a good pair of headphones.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like any guitar multi-effect with an **Aux in** will do the trick. You need an amplifier to use one - you can just plug in your guitar and your headphones (and your music source) and get going.

This site isn't really about specific equipment recommendations, but the [Zoom G1on](https://www.zoom.co.jp/products/guitar/zoom-g1on-guitar-multi-effects-processor) is an example of type of device I mean (this isn't a recommendation - I've not played that specific device).

If you'd like to get some recommendations, try one of the many traditional forums like [thegearpage](http://www.thegearpage.net).